# Ag-Grid custom sorting with modifier key

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a use case to cycle custom sort logic so that user could sort naturally as well as sort by absolute value if shift key is pressed.

Since custom sorting is defined in column definition there is no direct hook to grid, and unlike cell renderer - there is no way to read the context and get the state

In Ag-grid we can custom sort via compartor

```
const gridOptions = {
    autoGroupColumnDef: {
        field: 'athlete',
        comparator: function(valueA, valueB, nodeA, nodeB, isDescending) {
            //How do i detect if shift key is pressed at this point??
            return (valueA == valueB) ? 0 : (valueA > valueB) ? 1 : -1;
        },
    },
}
```

How can i hook up and detect if shift key is pressed at the point of sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently nodeA optionwrapper.gridOptions.context allows to get the grid level context directly

Comment: you can also manually set context variables from the parent component and access them in renderer components, effectively using it as a way to access the wrapper component from within the grid to call helper functions/etc... Maybe it could be used to reference some state variable when tab is clicked, but in my experience you'd have to do some re-setting of the coldefs with a new comparator to get it to work. Maybe there's another way, not sure though.